# Cocoapods: Framework Not Found For Architecture Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm building an app with a today extension and in order to share code between the app and the extension I have a framework target in my project. The problem is that since I imported `MMWormhole` so that the app and the extension can communicate my today extension target won't build. It gives me the following error:

`ld: framework not found MMWormhole for architecture x86_64`

The thing is that `MMWormhole` is only used in the `Core` target, which is a framework.

My `Podfile` looks roughly like this:

```
def testing
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.4'
end


target 'TodayExtension' do
    target 'TodayExtension' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        testing
    end
end

target 'MainTarget' do        
    target 'MainTargetTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        testing
    end
end

target 'Core' do
    pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 2.0.0'
    target 'CoreTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        testing
    end
end

target 'UITests' do
end
```

The thing is that when I build a separate project with that same target configuration and podfile I don't get the error and works fine.

A couple of ways I've managed to fix it are:

- Add `pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 2.0.0'` to the `TodayExtension` target in the podfile.
- Add `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/MMWormhole` to the `Framework Search Paths` field in the `TodayExtension` settings.

I'm just not happy with these solutions and don't understand why it isn't working without them. Any ideas of what I could look at?

Thanks!

EDIT:
After being able to reproduce it in an demo project, I created an issue in the Cocoapods repo https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7034

Comment: If Today target needs MMWormhole framework and if the target does not contain that framework, the error should occur everytime. How is your separate project working with this podfile?

Comment: @PuneetSharma MMWormhole is actually only used inside the `Core` target, that's why it works in the separate project.

Comment: MMWormhole is used to communicate between main app and its extensions. But if you have not used it in your Today Target, it should not look for MMWormhole in Today Target. But this is XCode, it has build issues. Maybe once you tried to build Today against MMWomhole and XCode has retained that info. Have you tried clean-build and more importantly magic trick of deleting yoir derived data folder after quuitting the XCode?

Comment: @PuneetSharma yep that is what's weird. I've tried clean build, removing derived data, `pod deintegrate` and installing pods again, nothing works. Thanks!